# Mount LVM partition from Ubuntu LiveCD/ISO

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, live-cd

I have an old Ubuntu server inside a Virtual Box. I migrated to a new laptop a while ago and now for whatever reason I can't remember the password nor ssh to the box.

Ordinarily I'd fire up a Live CD mount the appropriate partition and fix the problems that way. The problem is this box is on an LVM. The LiveCD doesn't seem to have lvm2 which is [allegedly what I'll need](http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2007/11/mounting-lvm-disk-using-ubuntu-livecd.html) to get the partition mounted.

I've tried up to 14.04 and no luck. Is there a way to pull this off with an Ubuntu disk or maybe a third party LiveCD/ISO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from fedora live cd or somesuch, run

```
vgchange -a y
```

if the volume groups are not visible already, and the volume groups logical volumes will appear for you to mount

Comment: Nice, I'll give this a try.

Comment: more details here https://zeldor.biz/2011/01/mount-lvm-from-livecd/